# TextChanged event firing as soon as I open the app

Tags: c#

So I am making an app in C# where it creates/edits existing .ini files. One of the features I am trying to add is that if I make changes to the .ini file via the c# app I created, and either try to close the app, open another .ini file or create a new file, it should prompt the user if they want to save the file. To accomplish this, I have a flag called *dataChanged*. In the TextChanged events in for the multiple textboxes, I set `dataChanged = true;` since changes were made to the file. However, for some reason as soon as I open the app, all the TextChange events fire up so even if I don't enter any values in the various textboxes, when I close the app, it prompts me to save the file (it shouldn't!). 
[image: Part of App AUI]

App UI:

User inputs text in the textboxes.

Part of code regarding the 4 textboxes:

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) //ifrs installer
        {

            dataChanged = true;

        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) //ifrs patchfile
        {

            dataChanged = true;
        }


        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
        {

            dataChanged = true;
        }

        private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
        {

            dataChanged = true;
        }
```

Comment: The `Text` property is already changed when it get's initialized, so your events will trigger. If you don't want the events to trigger that early, you should add  them programatically after the startup instead of binding them in the designer already.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seemed to have worked. Initially I set the value of the textboxes to TextBox in the XML of the UI. Then I deleted that portion and in the functipn `public MainWindow()`, I programatically set the values of textBoxes1 - 4 to equal *TextBox* and the TextChanged event still gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

TextChanged event fires even when you set some Text. Apparently you set some initial text when app is loading.

You can subscribe to the event mannually after you set the initial value.

```
textBox4.TextChanged += textBox4_TextChanged;
```

or unsubscribe before you set the value and subscribe after that.

```
textBox4.TextChanged -= textBox4_TextChanged;

textBox4.Text = "Initial Value";

textBox4.TextChanged += textBox4_TextChanged;
```

Comment: I tried to do the unsubscribe, change value and subscribe again but I get an error saying : The name *textBox_TextChanged* does not exist in current context. [Link to image](http://i.imgur.com/SLIkfSw.png)

Comment: @user2635911: Change the last line to subscribe to the same event handler. There is nothing to new. Eg: textBox1.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;

Comment: @user2635911: And you have to do this for all textBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're programmatically setting the textBoxN.Text properties.

What you might want to do is add an `if (appInitialized)` around your `dataChanged = true;` and only set `appInitialized` to true after the application is loaded, perhaps in your `Form_Load` event. This way, the initial loading doesn't set your variable. Another option is to only register the `TextChanged` event after you have already set the initial values. My guess is you registered the event using the designer and as a result it's firing for those initial settings because of where the designer adds event registration. Instead do the

```
textBox4.TextChanged += textBox4_TextChanged;
// Etc. for each text box
```

yourself after the .Text properties are set. Again, perhaps in your `Form_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are loading the ini file when the program loads and this triggers to text changed event.  I suggest doing something like this.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
    private bool _LoadingData = false;
    private bool _DataChanged = false;
    private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            _LoadingData = true;
            // Load data
        }
        finally
        {
            _LoadingData = false;
        }
    }
    public void DataChanged()
    {
        if (_LoadingData == false)
        {
            _DataChanged = true;
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataChanged();
    }
```